# Problem convert column values from VARCHAR(n) to DECIMAL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, data-conversion

I have a SQL Server 2000 database with a column of type VARCHAR(255). All the data is either NULL, or numeric data with up to two points of precision (e.g. '11.85'). I tried to run the following T-SQL query but received the error 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric'

```
SELECT CAST([MyColumn] AS DECIMAL)
FROM [MyTable];
```

I tried a more specific cast, which also failed.

```
SELECT CAST([MyColumn] AS DECIMAL(6,2))
FROM [MyTable];
```

I also tried the following to see if any data is non-numeric, and the only values returned were NULL.

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC([MyColumn]), [MyColumn]
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE ISNUMERIC([MyColumn]) = 0;
```

I tried to convert to other data types, such as FLOAT and MONEY, but only MONEY was successful. So I tried the following:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST([MyColumn] AS MONEY) AS DECIMAL)
FROM [MyTable];
```

...which worked just fine. Any ideas why the original query failed? Will there be a problem if I first convert to MONEY and then to DECIMAL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's likely that this depends on whether the decimal symbol is a comma or a dot.  Here are some test queries and their results:

```
select CAST('3.6' as decimal) -- 3.60
select CAST('3,6' as decimal) -- Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
select CAST('3.6' as money) -- 3.60
select CAST('3,6' as money) -- 36.00 (!)
select ISNUMERIC('3.6') -- 1
select ISNUMERIC('3,6') -- 1
```

The documentation for [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933213(SQL.80).aspx) says :

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input
>   expression evaluates to a valid
>   integer, floating point number, money
>   or decimal type; otherwise it returns
>   0

Both `3.6` and `3,6` can be cast to `money`, so that's why `isnumeric('3,6')` returns `1`.

To resolve this issue, replace the comma's with dots (or vice versa, if your system uses comma as the decimal symbol):

```
select cast(replace('3,6',',','.') as decimal)
```

Another option is to change the "decimal symbol" in Windows.  It's in Config Panel -> Regional and Language -> Formats -> Additional Settings -> Numbers.

Comment: It was a few records with commas instead of decimal points causing the problem. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 3):

Another cause is empty strings. For example, if you use the import wizard to import a CSV file, empty fields will become empty strings, not nulls.

This is a common idiom for fixing this:

```
CAST(NULLIF([number_as_a_string],'') AS decimal(13,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Select CAST(isnull(MyColumn,0) as Decimal(4,2))
FROM [MyTable];