# convert mysql type from varchar to decimal

Tags: mysql

when i was a noob, I developed a website to store daily expenses, and the expenses was saved as varchar. now I want to just alter the structure of the database (with all the thousands data inside) to decimal (which i found out is the best way to store currency stuff). my question is, will all the expenses data be intact? or will it corrupt anything?

Comment: woopps just found out that by directly converting the data type to decimal from varchar, it will remove the cents and so on!! luckily i did that on my local server first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest a layered approach:

- Alter the database structure and add a decimal field.
- Select the data from the database into the programming language of your choice.
- Convert the data with the language, write a SQL-script to insert (or insert them directly).
- Remove the VARCHAR field
- Rename the DECIMAL field to the name the VARCHAR field had.

Comment: if my language is PHP, any idea on the best method to 'Convert the data with the language'? thanks

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but it seems that floatval($val) converts a string into a floating point number, which is what you most probably need.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many thousands do you have...? If you have constants decimals (always 2 decimals for example) then you can change the type to `decimal(8,2)` 6 integers and 2 decimals. **If the data have less than 2 decimal 2.1 => 2.10** but in the other hand if you have more than 2 decimals then it will be **2.118 => 2.11** So be careful with this.

Make some CAST test, you may want to read this question: [Problem convert column values from VARCHAR(n) to DECIMAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589103/problem-convert-column-values-from-varcharn-to-decimal)