# Error in converting value from char to money

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `tableA` that contains a column `[Amount]` of datatype `varchar`.

It has values like:

```
47980.89
333652.61
332388.84
374664.48
368715.26
371689.33
371689.33
368715.26
374664.48
```

Now when I run my query, it runs successfully but gives different output each time

```
SELECT  
   sum(convert(float, Amount))
FROM tableA
```

and when I try this other statement, I get an error

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

Code:

```
SELECT  
    sum(convert(money, Amount))
FROM tableA
```

I want to have sum of the column `[Amount]`

Comment: `select cast(sum(amount) as money) from table group by...`

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589103/problem-convert-column-values-from-varcharn-to-decimal

Comment: @@VijayKumar :: amount is of varchar type

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Your column `Amount` **ought to be** of type `decimal(18,2)` - **NOT** varchar! Fix that, and all your problems with summing it will go away all by itself ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it:

```
select Sum(isnull(cast(amount as float),0)) from #t
```

or you need it to be money data-type

```
select Sum(isnull(cast(amount as money),0)) from #t
```

## [fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17994/1)

Comment: data  doesnot contain  any  null i have  tried using a where  condition against column

Comment: ok.. so can you post a sql fiddle for that.. jus make changes to my link and paste here

Comment: Is not the wrapper logic the other way round for correctness?  ie cast(isnull(  as the isnull pertains to the varchar status of the column value.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Amount AS MONEY)) From TableA where ISNUMERIC(Amount)=1
```

Comment: IF AMOUNT column  contains ',' then it will not be able to convert into float, but it was able to convert into float

Comment: @Himanshu.Parkash Which Sql Server , you are using? and do your column has any irrelevant values like null,nondigit string

Comment: Server 2012 and no my column doesnot contain any  irrelevant values