# Cannot convert a char value to money in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-analysis

I have a table called 'companyInfo' and the data type of 'Amount' is `nvarchar` and sample data looks like:

**companyInfo**

```
IDs | company   | year | Amount
----+-----------+------+-------
1   | Company A | 2011 | 40.00
2   | Company B | 2011 | Null
2   | Company C | 2011 | 100.00
4   | Company D | 2011 | 205.11
5   | Company E | 2011 | 0
6   | Company F | 2011 | Null
```

I wrote Query like below:

```
select IDs
  , company
  , sum(ISNULL(CAST(Amount AS MONEY), 0)) Amount
  , year
from companyInfo 
where Amount is not null 
  and year(cast(year as date)) = '2018'
group by IDs
  , company
  , Amount
  , year
```

got below Error:

> Error:
>   Msg 235, Level 16, State 0, Line 27
>   Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

Comment: Use try_convert(money,...)   it will return a NULL if the conversion fails rather than throwing an error.   To identity the problem values Select * from yourtable where try_convert(money,Amount) is null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in converting value from char to money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757714/error-in-converting-value-from-char-to-money)

Comment: Thank you @JohnCappelletti it worked by using ' try_convert' not sure why i was getting error when i used CAST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want..Both queries provide same results

Style 1

```
SELECT IDs
    ,Company
    ,FORMAT(YearFormed, 'yyyy') AS YearFormed
    ,Amount

FROM
(SELECT C.IDs, C.Company, CONVERT(DATE, C.YearFormed) AS YearFormed, CONVERT(MONEY, C.Amount) AS Amount FROM temp.dbo.CompanyInfo AS C) AS RC
WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL
```

---

Style 2

```
WITH RESULT AS --3-I named this query with the intention to formart the Year in which the companies were formed
(
SELECT IDs --1-Started from here
    ,Company
    ,CONVERT(DATE, C.YearFormed) AS YearFormed --2-I converted to Date here so I couldnt run format too so
    ,CONVERT(MONEY, C.AMOUNT) AS Amount
FROM temp.dbo.CompanyInfo AS C
WHERE C.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT R.IDs 
    ,R.Company
    ,FORMAT(R.YearFormed, 'yyyy') AS YearFormed --4-I used this SELECT statement only to format this column
    ,R.Amount
FROM RESULT AS R
```

This is what it gets as a result

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ZabiSidiqkhil this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because your regional settings.
Please, check with:

```
select
     IDs
     ,company
     ,sum(ISNULL(CAST(REPLACE(Amount, '.', ',') AS MONEY),0)) Amount
     ,year

from companyInfo 
    where Amount is not null 
    and year(cast(year    as date)) = '2018' 
    group by IDs,company,Amount,year;
```

You may debug the reason for the failure by running:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('205.11', '.', ',') AS MONEY),0)
```

Or

```
SELECT CAST('205.11'AS MONEY)
```

To isolate the issue

Comment: command              dbcc useroptions                                                                      to see the default language